# eclipse jsp formatter - inserts linebreaks in <script>

Tags: javascript, jsp, formatting, eclipse-indigo

I recently upgraded to eclipse indigo from galileo.  There has been some changes in the default formatter in my jsp pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var DAY = '<%=Constants.SALES_DAY%>';
  var WEEK = '<%=Constants.SALES_WEEK%>';
  var MONTH = '<%=Constants.SALES_MONTH%>';
  var YEAR = '<%=Constants.SALES_YEAR%>';
</script>
```

Ctrl-Shift-F on the file produces:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var DAY = '<%=Constants.SALES_DAY%>';
  var WEEK = '<%=Constants.SALES_WEEK%>';
  var MONTH = '<%=Constants.SALES_MONTH%>';
  var YEAR = '<%=Constants.SALES_YEAR%>
    ';
</script>
```

which breaks the page when deployed.  Where and how can I modify the setting responsible for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this post which helped and got info here.
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/769392/#msg_769392

looks like an eclipse bug.